# Dimension of singular curves of a given degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider plane curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. These are elements of the linear system $|O(d)|$.

What is the dimension of singular curves of degree $d$. Can this be computed? Is there some reference for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The locus of singular hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a divisor (called the discriminant) in the moduli space of hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. So, in your case, the dimension is $\dim |\mathcal{O}(d)| -1$.

Comment: @ Harry, can you direct me to some reference?

Comment: The following paper is classical: https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0013-8584&vol=58&iss=3&rank=5